# How put data from xlsread in global variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, global-variables, scope

I used the `uigetfile` function to select an XLS file. Then from inside a button callback function `open_xls_Callback` of my GUI, I read the text and number values from the excel file using:

```
[text,number,d] = xlsread(...)
```

How can I access variables `text` and `number` in other calback functions (a pushbutton for example)? How can I make those variable global and accessible from outside that function scope?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assignin` to put your variable in a given workspace.
In your case, if you mean by *global*, you mean *base workspace*, then use `assignin('base', 'variable_name_you_want', text)`.

If you truly wanted a *global variable*, then declare `global var_name_u_want` in the function and then assign `var_name_u_want = text`.

Answer (score 0):

All nested functions can access variables defined in their parent function. This can be used to share data across all callback functions.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```
function myGUI()
    %# this variable is accessible in both callback functions
    x = 0;

    %# a simple GUI to increment/show the variable x
    figure('Position',[300 300 350 150])
    uicontrol('style','pushbutton', 'String','increment', ...
        'Position',[50 50 100 30], 'Callback',@incrementCallback);
    uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','get', ...
        'Position',[200 50 100 30], 'Callback',@getCallback);

    %# callback functions
    function incrementCallback(src,evt)
        x = x + 1;
    end
    function getCallback(src,evt)
        msgbox( sprintf('x = %d',x) )
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]